# Python requests.post, cant use a file as "data" variable

Tags: python

```
    headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
with open("jsonattempt.txt","r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    json_data = "'" + data + "'"
response = requests.post('https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/search/Standard', headers=headers, data=json_data)
print(response)
```

Generally, there is a curl request like this:

```
    curl -X 'POST' \
      'https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/search/Standard' \
      -H 'accept: application/json' \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      -d '{
    "query": {
        "status": {
            "option": "online"
        },
        "type": "Turquoise Amulet",
        "stats": [
            {
                "type": "and",
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "id": "pseudo.pseudo_total_mana",
                        "value": {
                            "min": 47,
                            "max": 49
                        },
                        "disabled": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "sort": {
        "price": "asc"
    }
}'
```

Which returns a bunch of unnecessary things.

My json_data variable and jsonattempt.txt is the same as -d parameter, I add ' ' to start and to end:

```
{
    "query": {
        "status": {
            "option": "online"
        },
        "type": "Turquoise Amulet",
        "stats": [
            {
                "type": "and",
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "id": "pseudo.pseudo_total_mana",
                        "value": {
                            "min": 47,
                            "max": 49
                        },
                        "disabled": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "sort": {
        "price": "asc"
    }
}
```

I convert curl request to python which is the code on the top, I add the data as json_data and yeet the post request but keep getting 400 Bad Request.

Request 401 is Unauthorized AFAIK, so I dont need an OAuth2 key for this. How can I insert my json file appropiately to the request?

(Same exact json works on `https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/Chuanhsing/poe/1.0.0#/Trade/get_api_trade_fetch__items_` I am just asking how to insert my json file to requests.post correctly.)

Comment: Question is still unclear... Let me edit this.

Comment: Yeah fine now. Probably. Still unclear to me. This is what happens when beer is literally cheaper than water and coding at 2 am in the morning...

Comment: I think there is some garbled text in your `curl` example. Does your `curl` command really include `-d 'curl -X 'POST' 'https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/search/Standard' ...`?

Comment: Typo there! Ding ding!

Comment: Fixed! Probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you adding quotes around the JSON content? That doesn't make any sense. Those quotes aren't part of your `curl` request.  If you just write...

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}
with open("jsonattempt.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    response = requests.post(
        "https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/search/Standard",
        headers=headers,
        data=data,
    )
print(response)
```

...it works as expected.

And in fact you can further simplify that; you don't need to read in the file data yourself, you can let `requests` do that:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}
with open("jsonattempt.txt", "r") as f:
    response = requests.post(
        "https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/search/Standard",
        headers=headers,
        data=f,
    )
print(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

#  some codes here

with open("jsonattempt.txt","r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    json_data = json.loads(data)

#  rest of codes here
```

Your request requires json type data, while you are passing a string. The json.loads method converts string to json. Try it out.